# Apply CSS to children of a parent page in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hierarchy

So I'm trying to make a tweak to my company's [website](https://cabinedit.com/feature/scratches/) so that a tray of thumbnails will only appear on pages that aren't a part of the "featured" section of the homepage.

In my mind, some variation of this would make sense:

```
.parent-pageid-2204 .thumb-tray, 
.parent-pageid-2204. tray-toggle {
        display: none !important;
}
```

However, this line of code hides the tray and toggle on all pages. When the !important tag is removed, it doesn't affect any pages at all.

Is there another way that I can target specific pages (or children of pages) in Wordpress? This is the name of the page in HTML: `class="page-template-default page page-id-2121 page-child parent-pageid-2204 not-mobile"`

Even targeting `.page-id-2121` doesn't seem to affect the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
body.page-id-2204 .tray-toggle, 
body.page-id-2204 .thumb-tray {
display:none;
}
```

also make sure it's below anything that will display it. Check line 599 in your stylesheet. that says Display:block. And the css you added to hide it, is above line 599. Put it below it.

Comment: body.parent-pageid-2204 .tray-toggle,
 body.parent-pageid-2204 .thumb-tray {
  display: none;
 } 

^ This ended up working once I placed it after line 599.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a selector, it should be more specific than the one you are trying to overwrite:

```
.page-template-default.page.page-id-2121.page-child.parent-pageid-2204.not-mobile .tray-toggle,
.page-template-default.page.page-id-2121.page-child.parent-pageid-2204.not-mobile .thumb-tray {
    ...
}
```

(It combines all the classes you listed as classes of the `body` tag plus the child element classes  `tray-toggle` and `thumb-tray`. Since it also contains a `page-id` class, it only applies to that one page)

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately this would force me to update the CSS whenever they added a new page, but this ID system would work perfectly for me for other page-specific changes.